# atlassian module has been installed but import report not found

Tags: python

I have installed the module with below command in ubuntu2204:

```
$ pip3 install atlassian
Requirement already satisfied: atlassian in /home/funny/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.0.0)
```

But when try below python code in x.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from atlassian import Jira
```

When run list, package is there:

```
$ pip3 list |grep atlassian
atlassian               0.0.0
```

Below error happen:

```
$ ./x.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./x.py", line 2, in <module>
    from atlassian import Jira
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'atlassian'
```

Why install say success but import report error?

Comment: Are you maintaining any virtual env(venv)?
If yes, you need to install attlassian in venv.

Comment: Can you share result of the following command?
pip3 list

Comment: @FakharAhmad when run pip3 list, that package is there!

Comment: @FakharAhmad I do not run venv.

Comment: If you want to use JIRA, you can also use pip3 install jira

Comment: There is no attlassian package i was able to find.
In your log as well the version show's 0.0.0. I found atlassian-python-api that has the version 3.41.2 currently